# Обновить язык на Django oscar

Tags: python, django, локализация

Всем привет!

На локальном сервере меняю файл 
`oscar\lib\python2.7\site-packages\oscar\locale\ru_RU\django.po` (и `.mo` автоматом).

Язык меняется на сайте как надо, но когда на сервер заливаю эти два файла и делаю рестарт — это не срабатывает.

Как сделать, чтобы сервер принял новые языковые файлы?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать перменную окружения `LANGUAGE='ru_RU'`